# Thymeleaf code does not work when I try to iterate through List<String> or String[]

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this thymeleaf template code snippet

```
  `                      <tr th:each="file : ${files}">
                                <td>
                                    <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-success"
                                       th:href="@{/home/get-file/{file}(file = ${file})}">View</a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger"
                                       th:href="@{/home/delete-file/{file}(file = ${file})}">Delete</a>
                                </td>
                                <th scope="row" th:text="${file}">ExampleFile.txt</th>
                            </tr>`
```

it does not works when files is `String[]` and nothing is displayed when files is `List<String>` either

I have tried changing between the two different types.

Is there something wrong in the way I iterate? I believe the syntax is correct. Also, this is my `model:Model` just before the controller endpoint method returns and it looks like all the data is there:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMF1L.png)

'''UPDATE'''
This is how I pass the model:
'CONTROLLER'

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("fileUpload") MultipartFile file,
                               ->>Model model<--) throws IOException {
    fileService.addFile(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(), file, model);
    return "result";
}
```

'SERVICE'

```
public int addFile(Authentication authentication, MultipartFile multipartFile, Model model) throws IOException {
    String userName = authentication.getName();
    User user = userMapper.getUser(userName);
    Integer userId = user.getUserId();
    String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
    if (!fileIsDuplicate(userId, fileName)) {
        try {
            byte[] fileData = multipartFile.getBytes();
            String contentType = multipartFile.getContentType();
            String fileSize = String.valueOf(multipartFile.getSize());
            File file = new File(fileName, contentType, fileSize, (long)userId, fileData);
            int id = fileMapper.insertFile(file);
      -----> ------->>>model.addAttribute("files", fileMapper.getFilesByUserId(userId).toArray(new String[0]));
            model.addAttribute("result", "success");

            return id;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            model.addAttribute("result", "error");
            model.addAttribute("message", "Exception occurred while trying to save file.");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    model.addAttribute("result", "error");
    model.addAttribute("message", "You have tried to add a duplicate file.");
    return -1;
}
```

Please note that as it can be seen in the debugger session screenshot attached, by the time I am back up at the controller layer and about to return the View, the Model has files values in it, meaning that upon backend controller endpoint method return, the Model is not empty.

This is my home.html template

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body class="p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-black">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="logoutDiv">
                <form action="#" th:action="@{/logout}" method="POST">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary float-right" id="btn-logout">Logout</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="contentDiv" style="clear: right;">
                <nav style="clear: right;">
                    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-files-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-files" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-files" aria-selected="true">Files</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-notes-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-notes" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-notes" aria-selected="false">Notes</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-credentials-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-credentials" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-credentials" aria-selected="false">Credentials</a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-files" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-files-tab">
                            <form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="@{/file/upload}" method="POST">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row" style="margin: 1em;">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <label for="fileUpload">Upload a New File:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" id="uploadButton">Upload</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <div th:if="${not #strings.isEmpty(error)}" th:text="${error}"></div>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped" id="fileTable">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="width: 20%" scope="col"></th>
                                        <th style="width: 80%" scope="col">File Name</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr th:each="file : ${files}">
                                    <td>
                                        <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-success"
                                               th:href="@{/file/{file}(file = ${file})}">View</a>
                                        <a class="btn btn-danger"
                                           th:href="@{/file/delete/{file}(file = ${file})}">Delete</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td scope="row" th:text="${file}">ExampleFile.txt</td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr th:each="file : ${filess}">
                                        <td scope="row" th:text="${file}">File</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-notes" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-notes-tab">
                        <button style="margin: 0.25em;" type="button" class="btn btn-info float-right"
                                onclick="showNoteModal()" id="btnAddNewNote">
                            + Add a New Note
                        </button>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped" id="userTable">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width: 20%" scope="col"></th>
                                    <th style="width: 20%" scope="col">Title</th>
                                    <th style="width: 60%" scope="col">Description</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr th:each="note : ${notes}">
                                    <td>
                                        <button id="btnEditNote" type="button" class="btn btn-success"
                                                th:data-id="${note.getNoteId()}"
                                                th:data-title="${note.getNoteTitle()}"
                                                th:data-description="${note.getNoteDescription()}"
                                                th:onclick="showNoteModal(this.getAttribute('data-id'), this.getAttribute('data-title'), this.getAttribute('data-description'))">
                                            Edit
                                        </button>
                                        <a id="ancDeleteNote" class="btn btn-danger"
                                           th:href="@{/note/delete-note/{noteId}(noteId = ${note.getNoteId()})}">Delete</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <th id="tableNoteTitle" scope="row" th:text="${note.getNoteTitle()}">Example Note Title</th>
                                    <td id="tableNoteDescription" th:text="${note.getNoteDescription()}">Example Note Description</td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal fade" id="noteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="noteModalLabel"
                             aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="noteModalLabel">Note</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form action="#" method="POST" th:action="@{/note/add-note}" th:object="${newNote}">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="noteId" th:field="*{noteId}" id="note-id">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="note-title" class="col-form-label">Title</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="noteTitle" th:field="*{title}" class="form-control"
                                                       id="note-title" maxlength="20" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="note-description" class="col-form-label">Description</label>
                                                <textarea class="form-control" name="noteDescription" th:field="*{description}"
                                                          id="note-description" rows="5" maxlength="1000" required></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                            <button id="noteSubmit" type="submit" class="d-none"></button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <button type="button" id="btnSaveChanges" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#noteSubmit').click();">Save
                                            changes
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-credentials" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-credentials-tab">
                        <button style="margin: 0.25em;" type="button" class="btn btn-info float-right" onclick="showCredentialModal()">
                            + Add a New Credential
                        </button>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped" th:object="${credentials}" id="credentialTable">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="width: 20%" scope="col"></th>
                                        <th style="width: 35%" scope="col">URL</th>
                                        <th style="width: 20%" scope="col">Username</th>
                                        <th style="width: 25%" scope="col">Password</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
                                        <a class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <th scope="row">Example Credential URL</th>
                                    <td>Example Credential Username</td>
                                    <td>Example Credential Password</td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal fade" id="credentialModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="credentialModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="credentialModalLabel">Credential</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form action="#" method="POST">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="credentialId" id="credential-id">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="credential-url" class="col-form-label">URL</label>
                                                <input type="text" name= "url" class="form-control" id="credential-url" maxlength="100" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="credential-username" class="col-form-label">Username</label>
                                                <input type="text" name= "username" class="form-control" id="credential-username" maxlength="30" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="credential-password" class="col-form-label">Password</label>
                                                <input type="text" name= "password" class="form-control" id="credential-password" maxlength="30" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <button id="credentialSubmit" type="submit" class="d-none"></button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#credentialSubmit').click();">Save changes</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/home.js"></script>

        <script th:src="@{/js/jquery-slim.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/js/popper.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
        <!--For opening the note modal-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // For opening the note modal
            function showNoteModal(noteId, noteTitle, noteDescription) {
                $('#note-id').val(noteId ? noteId : '');
                $('#note-title').val(noteTitle ? noteTitle : '');
                $('#note-description').val(noteDescription ? noteDescription : '');
                $('#noteModal').modal('show');
            }

            // For opening the credentials modal
            function showCredentialModal(credentialId, url, username, password) {
                $('#credential-id').val(credentialId ? credentialId : '');
                $('#credential-url').val(url ? url : '');
                $('#credential-username').val(username ? username : '');
                $('#credential-password').val(password ? password : '');
                $('#credentialModal').modal('show');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my result.html template

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}">

    <title>Result</title>
</head>
<body class="p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-black">
    <div class="container justify-content-center w-50 p-3" style="margin-top: 5em;">
        <div th:if="${result == 'success'}" class="alert alert-success fill-parent">
            <h1 class="display-5">Success</h1>
            <span>Your changes were successfully saved. Click <a href="/home" id="aResultSuccess">here</a> to continue.</span>
        </div>
        <div th:if="${result == 'notSaved'}" class="alert alert-danger fill-parent">
            <h1 class="display-5">Error</h1>
            <span>Your changes were not saved. Click <a>here</a> to continue.</span>
        </div>
        <div th:if="${result == 'error'}" class="alert alert-danger fill-parent">
            <h1 class="display-5">Error</h1>
            <span th:text="${message}">Example Error Message</span>
            <span>Click <a href="/home" id="aResultFailure">here</a> to continue.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The syntax looks good to me. Show us please how do you pass the model.

Comment: To debug your Thymeleaf template code, comment out the `<a>` elements and add a `<p th:text="${file.name}"/>File</p>`. Does it display the file name? If it does, then your expression for the `href` is the problem.

Comment: Thank you but I have already tried the above, unfortunately with no luck. The template keeps resolving to empty <body></body>.

Comment: it has something to do with returning the result.html, while the bit I am trying to iterate is inside home.html. But from result.html I click and get back to home.html

Comment: Please add the full form. The fact that your submit has the model doesn't mean it is available when rendering the form (the GET request that is). You are sending files to the controller which you probably add, and I suspect you have an input type named `files`, which is what would  show up in the model. So pleas add your full form as well as your controller (not only snippets as that is far from the information needed to have a clear picture).

Comment: I updated the thread with my forms/templates.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason was that I was serving a result.html view and when I clicked from result.html to get back to home.html it was just an  element that took me to the home.html. Instead, when I added a request to the button that takes me back from the result view to the home view which is responsible for updating the model. I thought that the Model's information is preserved somewhere in the front end but I guess this is not the case?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).